# Run curl command to load data to hdfs via python/jython

Tags: python, curl, jython-2.7, streamsets

Unable to download the file to hdfs if the url contains spaces when we are executing the jython/python
**For example :** URL Contains spaces in the file name and directory path

```
> http://www.example.com/a bc/def/c h.csv
```

Command i tried with the url by escaping spaces with %20 or + symbol both didn't work.

executing below command by opening the shell in python like below. If the url doesn't contain spaces it happens correctly.

```
curl http://www.example.com/a bc/def/c h.csv | hadoop fs -put -f - /xyz/c h.csv
```

Comment: I don't see any python related stuff here? URLs must not contain a space, therefore the "+" or "%20" encoding is correct. This seems to be a server issue, hard to tell without a valid example URI.

Answer (score 1):

What about escaping the spaces with backslashes? Or surrounding the URL with quotation marks? Try:

`http://www.example.com/a\ bc/def/c\ h.csv` or `"http://www.example.com/a bc/def/c h.csv"`